# Calculate marginal CPA in Lift test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test, marketing

I want to measure the marginal Cost Per Accusation (CPA) for a treatment. The experiment is designed as follows:

- We have two groups: control and treatment
- For every group we measure cost and number of accusations:
- We measure the difference for costs and applications between the two groups
- marginal CPA = delta_costs/delta_applications
- We check if the marginal CPA is below a specific threshold, we accept the treatment.

My questions is, assuming the difference is significant, is it the right way to compare it to a threshold?  Because this measurement has a variance, and if we for example sample again we may get a different value.